# Excel VBA - slow loop execution

Tags: vba, excel

I created a loop (which worked perfectly yesterday) that copies a range of cells and then pastes their values one cell to the right, relative to each cell. The range consists of 91 cells and they're all separated by headers so I can't just select them all and paste the values since that "does not work on multiple selections." The idea is to copy the data from the "current day" range into the "previous day" range.

So today when I ran the macro, it was extremely slow, doing around 1 cell per second. Excel became non-responsive after a few seconds but I could still see what it was doing on the screen. When the "cursor" caused the screen to scroll down, there was a grey area where the rest of the worksheet would normally be, you know what non-responsive windows look like. As soon as the cursor hit that grey area, the loop started going fast and finished in under a second. The CPU usage initially was <1% but it went up to around 25% as soon as that happened.

I put the loop in its own subroutine since it was part of a bigger macro that changes dates and other values, but there was no effect. The other macro (which has no other loops) runs perfectly when I removed that loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code for the loop:

```
Sub PreviousDay()

    Dim CDay As Range
    Set CDay = Range("CurrentDay")

    For Each Cell In CDay
        Cell.Copy
        Cell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next Cell
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any formulas in these cells?

Comment: The cells which are being copied have a formula in them. It's a reference to a different range where I update today's data. It's a simple =A1 and it doesn't require recalculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PreviousDay()

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim CDay    As Range

    Set CDay = [CurrentDay]

    For Each rngCell In CDay
        rngCell.Offset(0, 1) = rngCell
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

What I have changed:

- you do not copy, but you refer the values
- `Cell` is really a bad name for a variable, as far as it is an object in VBA
- referring to named ranges in Excel looks nicer to me like this -  `[name_of_the_range]`

Comment: Wow that was instantaneous. Thank you. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Will break if `[CurrentDay]` is non-contiguous and will be slower than copying the whole range area at once. Rory's answer solves these flaws.

Comment: @user1016274 - imagine that the user wants to change the color of the cells, depending on values later. Then he needs a loop.

Comment: ^that and Rory's answer doesn't compile.

Comment: OP refers to "slow" explicitely in the topic - so speed is prime. There is no mentioning of any cell-specific handling in this problem, so no need to take every possibility into account. - Your answer still assumes that the named range is one area alone.

Comment: @user1016274 - man are you a troll? Test my solution in an empty excel file with named range, split the named range into 2 areas run it and be amazed.

Comment: No need to get personal! I tested both codes and both work - you could have mentioned that your code will work across multiple areas. We are all always learning. Still, copying a range object is IMHO far superior to copying single cells, performance-wise. Imagine one area with 10k cells - one loop instead of 10.000.

Comment: @user1016274 - well, its a great idea to test 4 lines of code before criticizing. And in my code I am not copying anything - I am taking values. The loop has one plus - it gives possibility to apply some rules later to the copied cells.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop at all for that:

```
Sub PreviousDay()
    With Range("CurrentDay")
        .Offset(, 1).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Edit: you do need to loop if it's not one contiguous range, but you can loop by areas:

```
Sub PreviousDay()
    Dim rgArea as Range
    For each rgArea in Range("CurrentDay").Areas
        rgArea.Offset(, 1).Value = rgArea.Value
    Next rgArea
End Sub
```

Comment: This gives me the following error:

Runtime error '1004'

Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Answer (score 0):

This would help:

try this `Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value` instead of this:

```
Cell.Copy
Cell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: OP: "[...] just select them all and paste the values [...]"

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign the value without copying and pasting, this should be faster and 'smoother':

```
Sub PreviousDay()
Dim CDay As Range
Set CDay = Range("CurrentDay")

    For Each cell In CDay
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Maybe Calculation of linked cells or Screenupdating will be a brake too, so you could disable that:

```
Sub PreviousDay2()
Dim CDay As Range
Set CDay = Range("CurrentDay")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For Each cell In CDay
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
    Next cell
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I did disable screen updating and auto-calculation but that didn't help sadly. Referring values instead of copying and pasting is a lot better though, thank you.